# Highlight keywords in a pdf using itextsharp and render it to the browser

Tags: pdf, itext, highlighting, memorystream

I have an existing pdf .I am using itextSharp to open the document and highlight keywords dynamically and when I save this into a file it works fine, but when I write it into a memory Stream and try to render it on the browser the highlights are not there.

Here is the code

```
public void SearchPDF()
    {


        //Create a new file from our test file with highlighting
        string highLightFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Highlighted.pdf");
        // Stream
        //Bind a reader and stamper to our test PDF


        var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "201400699428__1_00000.pdf");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(testFile);

        var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        System.Globalization.CompareOptions cmp = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None;
        //Create an instance of our strategy

        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

        //using (var fs = new FileStream(highLightFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        //{
            using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, m);

                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, m))
                {
                    //document.Open();
                    for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                    {
                        MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategyTest = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy("Ritual Bath", cmp);
                        var listener = new MyRenderListener();
                        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                        //Parse page 1 of the document above
                        using (var r = new PdfReader(testFile))
                        {
                            var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(r, currentPageIndex, strategyTest);
                        }

                        //Loop through each chunk found

                        foreach (var p in strategyTest.myPoints)
                        {

                            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found text {0} at {1}x{2}", p.Text, p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Bottom));
                            float[] quad = { p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Bottom, p.Rect.Right, p.Rect.Bottom, p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Top, p.Rect.Right, p.Rect.Top };

                            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(p.Rect.Left,
                                                           p.Rect.Top,
                                                           p.Rect.Bottom,
                                                           p.Rect.Right);

                            PdfAnnotation highlight = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(stamper.Writer, rect, null, PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quad);

                            //Set the color
                            highlight.Color = BaseColor.YELLOW;

                            //Add the annotation
                            stamper.AddAnnotation(highlight, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        //}


             //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
             //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=download_report.pdf");
             //Response.BinaryWrite(byteContent);
             //Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=download_report.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", m.ToArray().Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(m.ToArray(), 0, m.ToArray().Length);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Which browser, which PDF renderer and what are the versions of both? At a quick glance it appears you are doing everything correctly but my guess is that you are viewing the PDF in something that doesn't know how to handle annotations.

Comment: Doing everything correctly? I beg to differ. Take a look at `m`, it is used twice: once with a `PdfWriter` instance, once with a `PdfStamper`. That is terribly wrong, isn't it? Why is there a `Document` and `PdfWriter` instance in this example?

Comment: Well that's what I get for only giving it a quick glance!

Comment: This issue happens for both Chrome and Firefox. Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 and the renderer here is Chrome PDF Viewer. Firefox Version is 21 . In IE it works fine because IE does not use any customized plugin and renders the PDF  in Adobe's plugin.

Comment: @ChrisHaas can you please help me figure out the issue.

Comment: @Poulami, you partially have your answer already and it is just that those PDF renderers don't fully support the entire PDF syntax. Specifically, (and this is just an educated guess) it appears that those renders require an `Appearance` entry to exist for those annotations. The PDF spec gives very broad recommendations when it comes to how to visually render an annotation but it allows authors to very literally demand how they want it to appear. Acrobat creates annotations with both entries but iText only create's the first, leaving the second up to you.