# Highlight pdf in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control, highlight

I have one textbox and WebBrowser control. Want to open pdf in WebBrowser control and highlight words in pdf which is in that textbox.

Currently Using this code to open PDF in WebBrowsercontrol

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(Convert.ToString([PDFFilePath])));
```

Comment: Not sure you are able to do it without 3rdParty libs. You can try ITextSharp. Check this question ["Highlight words in a pdf using itextsharp, not displaying highlighted word in browser"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952183/highlight-words-in-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-not-displaying-highlighted-word-in-br)